# Unable to determine cause of SyntaxError: on line 17, <=100

Tags: python

I am having syntax errors on the below code and can't determine why. Additionally, if I comment out the `elif` statements, my line 12 does not actually add the variables together.

```
#Define variables and collect inputs
points =  int(input("How many points do you have?:  "))
years =  int(input("How many years have you been a customer?:  "))

points_discount = float()

years_discount = float()

final_discount = float()

#formula for additional discount
final_discount = points_discount + years_discount

#if statements for the points
if points <= 50:
    points_discount == 0.00
elif points > 50 and <= 100:  # SyntaxError here.
    points_discount == 0.10
elif points >100 and <=200:
    points_discount == 0.20
elif points >200 and <=300
    points_discount ==  0.25
else:
    points_discount == 0.30

#if statement for the years as a customer
if years < 5:
    years_discount  == 0.00
else:
    years_discount == 0.05

print(str(final_discount), " is your discount")
```

Comment: Why `points_discount = float()` instead of `points_discount = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax

```
if points <= 50:
    points_discount = 0.00
elif points > 50 and points<= 100:
    points_discount = 0.10
elif points >100 and points <=200:
    points_discount = 0.20
```

Comment: single equal for assignment, double for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems:

1. After every `if`, `for`, `while` etc, you have to use colons (`:`) - forgotten in line 21
2. `if` statements should consist of phrases which return `True` or `False`. You wanted to find out if variable is between 2 limits, you should do it like this - `elif points > 50 and points <= 100:` - which both of the phrases that to the left and right of `and` return boolean.

The whole solution without errors:

```
#Define variables and collect inputs
points =  int(input("How many points do you have?:  "))
years =  int(input("How many years have you been a customer?:  "))

points_discount = float()

years_discount = float()

final_discount = float()


#if statements for the points
if points <= 50:
    points_discount = 0.00
elif points > 50 and points <= 100:
    points_discount = 0.10
elif points >100 and points<=200:
    points_discount = 0.20
elif points >200 and points<=300:
    points_discount =  0.25
else:
    points_discount = 0.30

#if statement for the years as a customer
if years < 5:
    years_discount  = 0.00
else:
    years_discount = 0.05

#formula for additional discount

final_discount = points_discount + years_discount
print(str(final_discount), " is your discount")
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman thank  you  for the explanation. I see I was missing the variable of points on the right side of the if/elif statements.  Another question I have is line 12, the final print statement always prints 0.00 even with ```final_discount = points_discount + years_discount```

Comment: edited to solve your extra issue. that was because you used `==` instead of `=` for assignment. `==` is used to compare elements